# ESP32 Bluetooth connection lost after pairing

Tags: bluetooth, esp-idf

I'm trying to run the Classic Bluetooth "acceptor" example:

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/classic_bt/bt_spp_acceptor

With the same sdkconfig configuration settings as the example

I turn on the bluetooth in the phone. I select the ESP32 device.

Then pop up a window with the pairing number:
[image: Screenshot_20230615_111805_Settings~2]
At the same time this windows pops up, in the terminal i receive the following message:

**W (162921) BT_HCI: hcif conn complete: hdl 0x80, st 0x0**

**W (162940) BT_HCI: hcif link supv_to changed: hdl 0x80, supv_to 8000**

As soon as I pair the devices in the phone, the authentication is succesfull, but i receive the following message in the terminal:

**W (245220) BT_HCI: hci cmd send: disconnect: hdl 0x80, rsn:0x13**

**W (245296) BT_HCI: hcif disc complete: hdl 0x80, rsn 0x16**

And the connection process stops there. The connection proccess cannot complete.
The serial port callback never reach the state: **ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT** (SPP Server connection open)

I think is related with HCI.

[image: unnamed]

I tried with this configuration:
[image: unnamed]

And also tried with HCI instead of PCM

I tested both ESP32 WROOM 32 and ESP32 PICO MINI 02 and their behavior is slightly different

ESP32 WROOM 32 does not even pair

ESP32 PICO MINI 02 pair and disconnect, like the pictures above